# Flume, is there an acknowledgement than the event reach the channels?

Tags: flume, flume-ng

So in the flume architecture we have data send to a source, the source write to the channel and the channel send the event to the sink that does what it needs to do.

I currently have a flume agent using a memory channel, a AvroSource and and a HdfsSink.

To send data to the AvroSource, I use the flume-ng-sdk that propose me the appendBatch method.

This appendBatch method throw an exception if the event isn't delivered to "at least his next hop" as the [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.flume/flume-ng-sdk/latest/index.html) says.

> An event delivery exception is raised whenever an Event fails to reach at least one of its intended (next-hop) destinations.

But my question here is, what is the "intended next-hop destination" here ?
Is it the channel ? Or is it the source ?

I think it's very important and I struggle to understand it well.

Some use case needs to ensure that the event was received on the channel because it's on the channel that we have some persistence feature.